# Como recibir los parámetros getIntent().getExtras(); enviados desde otra App Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Estoy implementado la funcionalidad de abrir la App2 desde un Intent ejecutado de una App1, para esto es necesario que la App2 reciba parámetros para abrir desde la App1.

App1 -> Envia parametros para abrir -> App2

Cuando realizo esta operación por primera vez y la App2 está cerrada funciona bien porque se ejecuta el método onCreate() que es donde recibo los parámetros Bundle.

Pero cuando realizo la operación y la App2 ya esta abierta (o en segundo plano) no puedo recibir los nuevos parámetros Bundle desde App1 porque en la App2 se ejecuta el método onRestart() y no el onCreate() que es donde estoy recibiendo los parámetros. Por lo que siempre se mantienen los parámetros recibidos la primera vez.

Considerando el ciclo de vida de la actividad:
¿Como y donde es recomendable recibir los parámetros getIntent().getExtras(); en la App2 para que esto funcione con la app cerrada o abierta en segundo plano ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    Log.v(TAG, "===== onCreate()");


    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b != null) {
        Log.v(TAG, "===== Bundle recibido. Obtener los parametros " );
        param1 = b.getString("param1");
        param2 = ((int) b.getInt("param2")) + 1;
        param3 = (int) b.getInt("param3");
        param4 = (int) b.getInt("param4");

    }else{
        Log.e(TAG, "===== Bundle recibido es NULL. No se pueden obtener los parametros " );
    }

}

protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.v(TAG, "===== onStart(): ");
}
protected void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    Log.v(TAG, "===== onRestart(): ");

}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v(TAG, "===== onResume(): ");
}
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.v(TAG, "===== onPause(): ");
}
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.v(TAG, "===== onStop(): ");
}
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v(TAG, "===== onDestroy(): ");
}
```

Comment: Creo que deberías usar BroadcastRecievers, lee más acá https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#share-interaction-data

Answer (score 1):

Solucioné el problema creando una actividad intermedia en la App2 solamente para recibir los datos del Bundle enviados desde la App1, luego de eso, envió los datos a la actividad que necesito abrir en la App 2 para que siempre inicie con el método onCreate()

Actividad intermedia SplashScreen:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    //Recibir parametros desde la App1
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b != null) {
        param1 = b.getString("param1");
        param2 = ((int) b.getInt("param2")) + 1;
        param3 = (int) b.getInt("param3");
        param4 = (int) b.getInt("param4");

    }else{
        Log.e(TAG, "===== Bundle recibido es NULL. No se pueden obtener los parametros " );

    }

    
    Intent i = new Intent( SplashScreen.this , MiActividadFinal.class);
    i.putExtra("param1", param1);
    i.putExtra("param2", param2);
    i.putExtra("param3", param3);
    i.putExtra("param4", param4);
    startActivity(i);

    //Matar la actividad intermedia
    SplashScreen.this.finish();


}
```

Y en la App1 llamo a la App2 de la siguiente manera:

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //La actividad destino debe tener en el manifest android:exported="true"
            String id_aplicacion = "com.misapps.app2";
            String nom_actividad = id_aplicacion + ".SplashScreen";
            try {

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("param1", param1);
                i.putExtra("param2", param2);
                i.putExtra("param3", param3);
                i.putExtra("param4", param4);

                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
                i.setComponent(new ComponentName(id_aplicacion, nom_actividad) );
                ActividadApp1.this.startActivity(i);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + id_aplicacion) ));
            }

        }
    });
```

Saludos.

Comment: Creo que sería más fácil si implementaras el componente Navigation ya que al hacerlo solito maneja este tipo de cosas

Comment: @ParisN.Salguero Cual seria ese componente Navigation ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started?hl=es-419